# Difference between dumping and resetting with databases

Tags: database, django, terminology

I was just reading about [Django database fixtures](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures). Both dumping and resetting are mentioned.

It seems that dumping is to get rid of a specific data set in a database, and resetting erases all the data from the database. Is that right? Another possible difference I spotted is that maybe dumping is reversible, but resetting isn't?

Comment: Dumping...dumps the data, which you can reuse, import, backup or just erase, reset destroys both your tables and your data giving you practically an empty db.

Comment: Great, thanks. Want to make that an answer so I can mark it as official?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumping does what it says, dumps the data, which you can reuse, import, backup or just delete, reset destroys both your tables and your data giving you practically an empty db.
**Please bare in mind that reset no longer exists, it has been replaced with flush**